how to parse credit card expiration date format correctly using parser?
I am using the parser from dateutil python package, it is working fine for most dates but there are many places where it is working randomly. One example is: in a date string as 5/23, i am trying to mean May of 2023. But the parser parses this as 2024-05-23 00:00:00. As you can see, it took the 23 as the date and 5 as the month(which is correct) and it included the year 2024 I am guessing because that is the current year. How can i force my parser to not do it like this?
Things I have noticed
I know that if i give a 4 digit year, it does not take the default current year and hence the value is correctly parse, like 06/2025. I tried looking at the docs of the parser library but did not find anything useful.
Another weird thing I noticed is for dates like 5/86 it takes the 1900 i am guessing because it is closer? so 5/86 is parsed as 1986-05-30 00:00:00. Is there any option to stop this and only takes values in the future? Because for credit cards we cant have expiration dates in the past. I know we wont have credit cards with expiration dates 80 years in the future, but my code demands it specifically that we dont get a past date.
Another weird thing I noticed is for dates like 5/86 it takes the 1900 i am guessing because it is closer? so 5/86 is parsed as 1986-05-30 00:00:00. Is there any option to stop this and only takes values in the future? Because for credit cards we cant have expiration dates in the past. I know we wont have credit cards with expiration dates 80 years in the future, but my code demands it specifically that we dont get a past date.
My code:
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime


def date_string_to_datetime_conversion(date_string: str):
    try:
        return parser.parse(date_string, dayfirst=True)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        try:
            return parser.parse(date_string)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
            raise InvalidData(
                f"The expiration_date is a required column in a bankcard and must be in a valid date format. "
                f"Additional info {e}"
            )
            

date_string_list = ['05/23','6/2025','12/12','12/31','5/86','4/32']
# 2024-05-23 00:00:00
# 2025-06-30 00:00:00
# 2024-12-12 00:00:00
# 2024-12-31 00:00:00
# 1986-05-30 00:00:00
# 2032-04-30 00:00:00


for date_time in date_string_list:
    print(date_string_to_datetime_conversion(date_time))


"it included the year 2024 I am guessing because that is the current year. How can i force my parser to not do it like this?" - how do you want the output to look like?

If given a date_string as 5/23, I want it to process it as 2023 year and the 5th month may. So it should be May 2023. Instead it takes 23 as the date and 5th as the month and defaults the year to 2024. How to make it read 23 as the year? What to do so it can read formats of type %mm/%yy?

It's technically not possible to create a date object with only a month and a year, so I would advise you to arbitrarily select e.g. the first of the month. The following code should be able to parse the dates as you described:
from datetime import datetime

def parse_date(date_str):
    month, year = date_str.split("/")
    month = int(month)
    year = int(year)
    if year < datetime.now().year:
        year = 2000 + year
    try:
        return datetime(year, month, 1)
    except:
        print("Invalid date passed.")

A key assumption here is that if the year in the input date string has less than four digits, then we guess that is between 2000-2999.

Your logic is definitely working for my cases, now I am thinking about how to isolate the 2digit year formats so this code block can handle those cases. I am thinking of using a regular expression to catch these cases, because my code is working fine for all other date formats.
